# Correct Pronunciation of 'Quiz'

Tags: pronunciation

How to pronounce the word 'quiz' correctly , some of my friends say 'KWIZ' and some others say 'KYUZ'. which one is the correct ?

Comment: [Quiz](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/british/quiz) on Cambridge Dictionaries Online.

Comment: thanks , /kwɪz/ is the correct one, so i can stop them arguing for KUIZ

Comment: sorry, kyuz i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kwiz

Go here to hear a native speaker say it: [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/quiz)